# Настройка PhpMailer для Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно отправлять письма с помощью SMTP, для этого я использую PhpMailer, как можно настроить чтоб письма отправлялись именно через эту библиотеку?

Comment: Для плагина  Contact Form 7

Answer (score 1):

"Настроить" PHPMailer для работы в WordPress без написания своего плагина или редактирования того же Contact Form 7 скорее всего не получится. Да, это и не нужно. Для WordPress есть целый ряд плагинов, которые позволяют отправлять почту в нужном формате через нужный SMTP сервер.

PHPMailer всё-таки больше подходит для самописных сайтов.